# Static method to get object from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, static-methods

I'm using Entity Framework to get data from the database. Now I have a hard time wrapping my head around static methods. I have an Users class and have this method defined in this User class:

```
public static User Get(int userId)
{
    using (DbContext ctx = new DbContext())
    return ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
}
```

Then I will use it like `User currentUser = User.Get(1)` and make changes to it before I save it again. Will this cause problems if there are more than 1 request virtually at the same time?

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

Potentially it will cause issues, especially when you attempt to update. There is not enough information here to give you a specific answer. Review locking for the database product you are using and EF documentation.